# What is the solution (tightest upper bound for runtime) of $T(n) = 2T(n/4) + O(n^2 \log n)$?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm trying to find the tightest upper bound for runtime of a function whose recurrence relation is the following: $T(n) = 2T(n/4) + O(n^2 \log n)$

I got $O(n^2 \log n)$ but I'm not sure if that is correct. I arrived to the solution using the Advanced master theorem: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/advanced-master-theorem-for-divide-and-conquer-recurrences/#

Comment: Would you mind to include your reasoning?

Comment: You can try to apply the $3$rd case of the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Generic_form).

Comment: You can verify the bound using the substitution method. Another way is to expand the recurrence.

Answer (score 1):

One way to arrive at the desired bound is to expand the recurrence. We will compute the first few iterations and then generalise. The first one is:

$$T(n) = n^2 \lg n + 2T\left( \frac{n}{4} \right)$$

Then:

$$T(n) = n^2 \lg n + 2 \left( \frac{n}{4} \right)^2 \lg \frac{n}{4} + 2^2 T\left( \frac{n}{4^2} \right)$$

And after one more:

$$T(n) = n^2 \lg n + 2 \left( \frac{n}{4} \right)^2 \lg \frac{n}{4} + 2^2 \left( \frac{n}{4^2} \right)^2 \lg \frac{n}{4^2} + 2^3 T\left( \frac{n}{4^3} \right)$$

Now we generalise to:

$$T(n) = \sum_{i = 0}^{\frac{1}{2} \lg n} \frac{1}{8^i} n^2 \lg \frac{n}{4^i} + \sqrt{n} $$

$$= n^2 \lg n \sum_{i = 0}^{\frac{1}{2} \lg n} \frac{1}{8^i} - n^2 \sum_{i = 0}^{\frac{1}{2} \lg n} \frac{2i}{8^i} + \sqrt{n} $$

We can bound $T(n)$ from below:

$$T(n) \geq n^2 \lg n \sum_{i = 0}^{\frac{1}{2} \lg n} \frac{1}{8^i} - n^2 \sum_{i = 1}^{\frac{1}{2} \lg n} \frac{1}{4^i} + \sqrt{n}$$

And from above:

$$ T(n) \leq n^2 \lg n \sum_{i = 0}^{\frac{1}{2} \lg n} \frac{1}{8^i} + \sqrt{n} $$

The bound $\frac{1}{2} \lg n$ is the number of times $n$ needs to be divided by $4$ to reduce $n$ to $O(1)$, i.e. $n = 4^k = 2^{2k}$ and so $k = \frac{1}{2} \lg n$. Computing the geometric series gives:

$$ T(n) \geq \frac{8}{7} n^2 \lg n - \frac{1}{7} \sqrt{n} \lg n - \frac{1}{3} n^2 + \frac{1}{3} n + \sqrt{n}$$

$$T(n) \leq \frac{8}{7} n^2 \lg n - \frac{1}{7} \sqrt{n} \lg n + \sqrt{n}$$

And so we conclude $T(n) = O(n^2 \lg n)$, which we can verify using the substitution method. Removing lower order terms we assume $T(n) \leq c n^2 \lg n$. Now we substitute into the recurrence relation:

$$T(n) = 2T\left( \frac{n}{4} \right) + kn^2 \lg n $$
$$T(n) = 2\left( c \left( \frac{n}{4} \right)^2 \lg \frac{n}{4} \right) + kn^2 \lg n $$

$$T(n) = \frac{c}{8} n^2 \lg \frac{n}{4} + kn^2 \lg n$$
$$T(n) = \frac{c}{8} n^2 \lg n - \frac{c}{4} n^2 + kn^2 \lg n$$
$$T(n) = \left( \frac{c}{8} + k\right)n^2 \lg n - \frac{c}{4} n^2$$
$$T(n) \leq cn^2 \lg n$$

The last inequality holds for sufficiently large $c$, e.g. $\frac{8}{7} k \leq c$. Which shows that $T(n) = O(n^2 \lg n)$ as you thought. We could have also verified the bound by plugging the recurrence relation into a tool like [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=T%28n%29%3D2T%28n%2F4%29+%2B+n%5E2+log%28n%29%2C+T%281%29%3D1) which gives the desired upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the recurrence

$$
T(n) = 2 T\left(\frac n4\right)+k n^2\log_4n
$$

making $n=4^m$ we have

$$
T\left(4^m\right)=2T\left(4^{m-1}\right)+k m 4^{2m}
$$

This recurrence can be recast as

$$
R(m) = 2R(m-1)+k m 4^{2m}
$$

This is a linear recurrence and can be solved as

$$
R(m) = R_h(m) + R_p(m),\ \ \ \cases{R_h(m) = 2R_h(m-1)\\ R_p(m) = 2R_p(m-1)+k m 4^{2m}}
$$

The homogeneous has solution

$$
R_h(m) = c_02^m
$$

now assuming $R_p(m) = c_0(m)2^m$ after substitution into the particular we have

$$
c_0(m)2^m = 2 c_0(m-1)2^{m-1}+k m 4^{2m}
$$

or

$$
c_0(m) = c_0(m-1) + k m 2^{3m}
$$

with solution

$$
c_0(m) = \frac{8}{49} k \left(2^{3m} (7 m-1)+1\right)
$$

then

$$
R_p(m) = \frac{8}{49} k \left(2^{3m} (7 m-1)+1\right)2^m 
$$

and thus

$$
R(m) = \left(c_0+\frac{8}{49} k \left(2^{3m} (7 m-1)+1\right)\right)2^m
$$

and now going backwards with $m = \log_4 n$ we obtain

$$
T(n) =  \left(c_0\sqrt{n}+\frac{8}{49} k \left(n^2 \left(7\log_4 n-1\right)+\sqrt{n}\right)\right) = O\left(n^2\log_4 n\right)
$$